# Selecting specific rows from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which I have read with pandas. It contains a list of houses sold in Mumbai, with details like price, location, area etc. It looks like this:

```
       Price  Area  Location  ...  Gas_Connection  Jogging_Track  Swimming_Pool
0    4850000   720  Kharghar  ...           False          False          False
1    4500000   600  Kharghar  ...           False           True           True
2    6700000   650  Kharghar  ...           False           True           True
3    4500000   650  Kharghar  ...           False          False          False
4    5000000   665  Kharghar  ...           False          False          False
```

I want to perform operations on prices of houses in a particular locality. I there a way to use the prices of only the rows with Khargar as its locality? Just for some context there are about 6,500 entries in the df.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if df is the data frame then this will give you a new dataframe with just those in the area Khargar

```
dfNew = df[df['Location’] =='Khargar']
```

Comment: @AryaMan yes... `df[df['col'].isin([val1, val2])]`

Comment: thanks. I used df_1 = df.loc[(df['Location']=='Airoli') | (df['Location']=='Nala Sopara')]. 
 '|' Bitwise operator. But your solution is more elegant

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this:

```
    select_price = df.loc[df['Location'] == 'Kharghar']
    print (select_price)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = merged = pd.DataFrame({'Location' : ["Kharghar", "Khargar","NC"],
                            'Price' : [100, 10, 20,]
                            })
idx = np.multiply(df['Location'] == "Kharghar",1)
prices = df['Price'][idx == 1]
print(prices)
```

The piece of code you need,

```
idx = np.multiply(df['Location'] == "Kharghar",1)
prices = df['Price'][idx == 1]
print(prices)
```

Or,

```
idx = df['Location'] == "Kharghar"
prices = df['Price'][idx == True]
print(prices)
```

Comment: if you're not going to use the multiple built-in pandas slicing methods, I would recommend np.where or np.argwhere over this..you also don't need to mask a boolean array, you can just use it directly

Comment: Thanks for your kind feedback. I generally use like "or option"  to enhance readibility.